# Ansible, run task if playbook includes role

Tags: ansible

Let's imagine a playbook with following roles: base, monitoring, nginx and another playbook with only base and nginx.

Now I want in monitoring role to run a task only if playbook includes nginx role, because for monitoring nginx I have to pass a little bit different configuration to monitoring service.

How to execute a task what dependes on another role existence?

Comment: Does not directly answer your question but as a workaround, perhaps make monitoring part of your _nginx_ role? Would you ever want un-monitored servers?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to set fact with set_fact in nginx role (set_fact: nginx=True) and then check it in monitoring role and execute task when fact is defined and true ( when: (ansible_facts['nginx'] is defined) and (ansible_facts['nginx'] == True)).

Answer (score 1):

While my workaround in the comments might have worked for you, I feel it's still not the best approach. It's not modular. For example in a situation where you change monitoring system, you'd need to go into each role and check if it has monitoring component and update that...Not the most optimal way.

Perhaps a better way would be to still include a separate *monitoring* role, but there execute specific tasks using *[playbook conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html)*. For example, *nginx* monitoring task would execute only `when` this server is part of your *[webservers]* group. Or when a certain variable is set to a specific value or some other appropriate conditional is met.

Comment: It becomes a mess this way